# The Data So Far

Tags: metapuzzles

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

If you've been following this xkcd series of puzzles, you know that 11 of the 13 subpuzzles have been solved so far.

- [Consecutive Vowels](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66359/consecutive-vowels)
- [Chess Enlightenment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66441/chess-enlightenment)
- [Island (sketch)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66527/island-sketch)
- [Labyrinth Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66580/labyrinth-puzzle)
- [No Pun Intended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66661/no-pun-intended)
- [Listen to Yourself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66703/listen-to-yourself)
- [Real Programmers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66743/real-programmers)
- [Arsenic Based Life](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66806/arsenic-based-life)
- [Iambic Pentameter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66857/iambic-pentameter)
- [Self-Description](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66927/self-description)
- [Five-Minute Comics: Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66968/five-minute-comics-part-1)
- [I Don't Want Directions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67017/i-dont-want-directions)
- [Five-Minute Comics: Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67038/five-minute-comics-part-2)

Your final answer is one of the panels from an xkcd comic.

Comment: Holy moly, the amount of planning this took! Too bad I can only upvote once.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The answers to the 13 puzzles are, in order of puzzle posted:

> Consecutive Vowels: **I WANT TO BE TOUCHING YOU**
>  Chess Enlightenment: **KNIGHT TO BE ONE WITH NATURE**
>  Island (sketch): **EXILE**
>  Labyrinth Puzzle: **MIDNIGHT**
>  No Pun Intended: **SUPERINTENDING**
>  Listen to Yourself: **EUREKA**
>  Real Programmers: **SPACETIME**
>  Arsenic Based Life: **AS YOU LIKE IT**
>  Iambic Pentameter: **PROSTHETIC FEET**
>  Self-Description: **THIS TEXT IS THE ANSWER**
>  Five-Minute Comics: Part 1: **UMMM SOME CREATIVE PUN OR SOMETHING**
>  I Don't Want Directions: **LOST FOREWORDS**
>  Five-Minute Comics: Part 2: **MATRIX FIGURE**

The meta connection is:

> Each answer contains exactly one occurrence of one of the letters X, K, C, or D. Each instance appears at a unique place in the answer, from 1st to 13th. (That is, for one answer the XKCD letter is first; for another answer, it's second; and so on.) This provides an ordering for the answers.

Using this to extract an answer:

> In this order, the answers are:
>  `. K N IGHTTOBEONEWITHNATURE`
>  `.E X I LE`
>  `.MI D N IGHT`
>  `.SPA C E TIME`
>  `.EURE K A`
>  `.MATRI X F IGURE`
>  `.THISTE X T ISTHEANSWER`
>  `.ASYOULI K E IT`
>  `.UMMMSOME C R EATIVEPUNORSOMETHING`
>  `.PROSTHETI C F EET`
>  `.SUPERINTEN D I NG`
>  `.LOSTFOREWOR D S`
>  `.IWANTTOBETOU C H INGYOU`
>  The letters after the XKCD letters spell the message "NINEAFTERFISH".
>  "NINE AFTER FISH" indicates that we should start at the XKCD comic titled *Fish*, which is [#1377](https://xkcd.com/1377/), and then go nine comics forward to [#1386](https://xkcd.com/1386/).
>  The final answer is then a panel from this comic.

Final answer panel:

> Since OP is a nice person who wants to reward their solvers, I expect this is the final answer:
>  [image]
>  A wonderful reward for all of us here at PSE! May we continue to share our wisdom with all. I haven't prepared a speech for accepting this reward on behalf of the community, so here's a list of Thank-Yous.
>  Special thanks to [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66368/48964), [Thomas Blue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66504/48964), [Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66547/48964), [ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66584/48964), [the PSE Community (esp. Bass)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66675/48964), [noedne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66707/48964), [Persona](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66744/48964), [phenomist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66807/48964), [Sid et al.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66864/48964), [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66929/48964), [Deusovi and SKOG](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66970/48964), [Deusovi and Level 51](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/67021/48964), and [Deusovi and phenomist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/67040/48964).
>  **Super special thanks to the OP [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827) for creating this quite simply astounding meta suite in just two weeks, and all within the Fortnightly Topic Challenge!**